# How to inject springSecurityService into custom Listener

Tags: grails, dependency-injection, spring-security

I'm using Grails 1.3.7 alogn with SpringSecurity and have a requirement where I need to perform a little processing when a users session expires.

So I have a defined a class in src/groovy which implements HttpSessionListener and overrides the sessionDestroyed method. The listener class is defined as a 'listener' in web.xml.

I have added a 'def springSecurityService' into the listener which I was hoping would automatically inject the service but this doesn't appear to be the case.

So I am wondering what else I need to do in order for the injection to take place, do I have to declare the listener class in resources.groovy somehow?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listeners are instantiated by servlet container, and are thus outside of Spring's reach. However, you can get to the application context through servletcontext (available in the session object). Something like this should get you the service:

In 2.0.0 you can use:

```
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    ServletContext context = se.getSession().getServletContext();
    GrailsApplication application = GrailsWebUtil.lookupApplication(context);
    application.getMainContext().getBean("springSecurityService");
}
```

In previous versions, *GrailsWebUtil.lookupApplication()* is not available, but you can use *org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder.getApplication()* instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input however on the call to lookupApplication I'm receiving a No signature of method: static grails.util.GrailsWebUtil.lookupApplication() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade) exception.

Comment: Ok, making progress and now able to get the service, unfortunately however the currentuser is null. So not sure if thats because spring has already unloaded it before the sessionDestroyed event is fired, or for some other reason.

Comment: Yeah, lookupApplication() is a 2.0.0 feature (edited my answer to reflect it). As for springSecurityService.getCurrentUser(), it's possible that the security context is held only during a request. As the event listeners fire outside of request context, the security context would not be available. I'm not an expert on Spring Security, but that is a common pattern.

Comment: Yep thats what I've done, as found the Log4J code was doing the same using : def ctx = AH.application.mainContext and    springSecurityService = ctx.springSecurityService

Comment: Then you can probably accept my answer, as it solves your injection issues? :) You should maybe open up a new question regarding the intricacies of using spring security currentUser outside a request context...

Answer (score 0):

In 2.0 and later, you can use plugin spring-security-core:2.0-RC4

Installation in BuildConfig.groovy   compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC4'

```
Class MyController {
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def springSecurityService
    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        def user = (User)springSecurityService.currentUser
        respond User.list(params), model: [userInstanceCount: User.count() ]
    }
}
```

More information to http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/

Hope that's help